# PDF to txt conversion: why does txt.write() not work?

Tags: python, pdftotext, pypdf

What I am trying to do here is convert a pdf to a text file. This txt is not a pre-existing one, but it is created with `creaty`. The problem is that although `writy.write()` has worked fine in other scripts, it won't do anything to change the `writy` file now, so it remains blank. What should I change?
thanks

p.s. the encoding in both `open` exists because there is u\u0152 within the result

```
import PyPDF2

pdfFileObj = open('Computer_science_paper_1__HL.pdf', 'rb')
creaty = open('Computer_science_paper_1__HL.txt', 'w+', encoding="utf-8")
writy = open('Computer_science_paper_1__HL.txt', 'a', encoding="utf-8")

pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

for x in range(1,pdfReader.numPages):
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(x)
    result = pageObj.extractText()

    writy.write(result)
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the `result` variable to standard output, so you can verify that `PyPDF2` actually finds something when you call `extractText()`

Comment: yes, the actual code contains `print (result)` just before the last line; I omitted it here because I thought it was trivial. It does give the correct output though

Comment: when do you close writy? the file is buffered, it won't actually be written until either a `flush` or a `close` is called. if the data is big enough, I'd expect some output, but if the buffers are big enough you might not get anything. it's safer to do `with open('file', 'a') as writy: <some stuff>`...

Comment: umm, I never closed it. Now it works, thanks a lot :)